# Suppose $b$ is the smallest element of $B$. Then $b$ is also a minimal element of $B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, relations, natural-deduction

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 206)

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$, and $B \subseteq A$.
>   Suppose $b$ is the smallest element of $B$. Then $b$ is also a minimal element
>   of $B$, and it is the only minimal element.

In this post, [Suppose $b$ is the smallest element of $B$. Then $b$ is also a minimal element of $B$, and it is the only minimal element.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3708692/suppose-b-is-the-smallest-element-of-b-then-b-is-also-a-minimal-element-o), I showed that the minimal element is unique. Now, I will prove premise two of that proof (that $b$ is also a minimal element of $B$).

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{
1.\, \forall x\forall y((xRy \land yRx) \to x=y)\\
2.\, b \in B \land \forall x(x \in B \to bRx)
}{
 \fitch{3.\, \exists x(x \in B \land xRb \land x \neq b)}{
   \fitch{4.\, a \in B \land aRb \land a \neq b}{
     5.\,\forall x(x \in B \to bRx) \ce{2}
     6.\,a \in B \to bRa \Ae{5}
     7.\,a \in B \ce{4}
     8.\,bRa \ie{6,7}
     9.\,(aRb \land bRa) \to a = b \Ae{1}
     10.\,aRb \ce{4}
     11.\,aRb \land bRa \ci{10,8}
     12.\,a=b \ie{9,11}
     13.\,a \neq b \ce{4}
     14.\,\bot \ne{12,13}
  }\\
  15.\,\bot \Ee{3,4-14}
}\\
16.\,\neg \exists x(x \in B \land xRb \land x \neq b) \ni{3-15}
17.\,b \in B \ce{2}
18.\,b \in B \land \neg \exists x(x \in B \land xRb \land x \neq b) \ci{17,16}
}
$

Why do I need to add "$x \in B$" in the symbolisation of "$b$ is a minimal element of B" in order to accomplish the proof ?

Is this proof correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation is correct. Note that you only need that $R$ is antisymmetric to prove that the smallest element of $B$ is a minimal element of $B$.

The formula
$$\tag{1}\lnot \exists x (xRb \land x \neq b)$$
means that $b$ is a minimal element for the domain of quantification, that is the set $A$ and *not* the subset $B$. Indeed, $\lnot \exists x$ means that there is no $x$ in the domain.

The fact that $b$ is the smallest element of $B \subseteq A$ does not imply that $b$ is a minimal element of $A$. For instance, if $A = \{0,1\}$ and $B = \{1\}$ with the usual order, then $B \subseteq A$, and $1$ is the smallest element of $B$ but is not a minimal element of $A$.

This is the reason why it is important to add $x \in B$ to $(1)$ and get
$$\tag{2} \lnot \exists x (x \in B \land xRb \land x \neq b)$$
which actually means that there is no element in $B$ smaller than $b$. According to $(2)$, possibly $b \in A \smallsetminus B$, so formula $(2)$ alone does not mean that $b$ is a minimal element of $B$.
But formula $(2)$ in *conjunction* with $b \in B$ means that $b$ is a minimal element of $B$.

From a technical point of view, in your derivation you can easily see the need for adding $x \in B$ to $(1)$.
Suppose that your line $3$ were $\exists x (xRb \land x \neq b)$, which means that $b$ is not a minimal element of $A$.
As in line $3$ there would not be $x \in B$, you cannot infer $a \in B$ in line $7$ and hence you cannot derive $bRa$ in line $8$ (which is essential to use antisymmetry and conclude that $a = b$ in line 12, so that you get a contradiction and thus derive that $b$ is a minimal element of $B$).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Taroccoesbrocco ! One question: in the formula, $$\lnot \exists x (xRb \land x \neq b)$$ I see $b$ belongs to $A$, but for that reason, isn't it necessary to add $b \in B$ to that formula? The addition of $x \in B$, specifies which set $x$ belongs, but still $b$ could belong to $A$. Perhaps, I am confused about it.

Comment: What's a minorant ?

Comment: @F.Zer - A minorant of $B \subseteq A$ is a element $b \in A$ smaller than all the elements of $B$. I've just  reworded the sentence without using "minorant" to avoid too many concepts (moreover the previous version was slightly inaccurate).

Comment: I understand, now. Thank you !

Comment: @F.Zer - The formula $\lnot \exists x (x \in B \land x R b \land x \neq b)$  means that $b$ is an element of $A$ such that there is no element in $B$ smaller than $b$. It doesn't mean that $b$ is a minimal element of $B$, because maybe $b \notin B$. I reworded the sentence to make it clearer (I hope!).

Comment: That's perfectly clear !

Comment: I am re-reading your answer and wondered about the example you gave,  @Taroccoesbrocco. When you said: "$1$ is the minimal element of $B$ but is not a minimal element of $A$"; what's the relation you had in mind ? How do you know is not a minimal element of $A$ ?

Comment: @F.Zer - The usual order on $\{0,1\}$: $0 \leq 0$, $1 \leq 1$ and $0 \leq 1$, but $1 \not \leq 0$.

Comment: Good. Then, in your example, $A$ does not have minimal element. Is that correct ?

Comment: @F.Zer - No. $A$ has a minimal element, $0$, which is not the minimal element of $B$.

Comment: Thank you ! I read the definition of minimal element reversed. Sorry. No element satisfies $xR0$ other than $0$. So, $0$ is the minimal element.